# Python Character Encoding European Accents

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I know this is not an uncommon problem and that there are already multiple SO questions answered about this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833440/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe9-in-position-7), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994899/encoding-for-multilingual-py-files), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)) but even in following the recommendations there, I am still seeing this error (for the below code):

`uri_name = u"%s_%s" % (name[1].encode('utf-8').strip(), name[0].encode('utf-8').strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

So I am trying to get a url from a list of artist names, a lot of which have accents and european characters like so (with their names also printed with the special characters via `repr`):

```
Auberjonois, René -> Auberjonois, Ren\xc3\xa9
Bäumer, Eduard -> B\xc3\xa4umer, Eduard
Baur-Nütten, Gisela -> Baur-N\xc3\xbctten, Gisela
Bösken, Lorenz -> B\xc3\xb6sken, Lorenz
Čapek, Josef -> \xc4\x8capek, Josef
Großmann, Rudolf -> Gro\xc3\x9fmann, Rudolf
```

The block I am trying to run is:

```
def create_uri(artist_name):

  artist_name = artist_name

  name = artist_name.split(",")

  uri_name = u"%s_%s" % (name[1].encode('utf-8').strip(), name[0].encode('utf-8').strip())

  uri = 'http://example.com/' + uri_name

  print uri

create_uri('Name, Non_Accent')
create_uri('Auberjonois, René')
```

So the first one works and produces `http://example.com/Non_Accent_Name`
But the second fails with the error above.

I have added `# coding=utf-8` to the top of my script and have tried encoding the `artist_name` string at every point along the way, only to get the same error each time.

If it matters, I am using Atom as a text editor and when I open up the .csv file from where these names are coming from, the accents all display correctly.

What else can I do to ensure that the script interprets UTF-8 as UTF-8 and not ascii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using UTF-8. Use `unicode`s everywhere, and only decode/encode (if necessary) at interfaces.

```
def create_uri(artist_name):
  name = artist_name.split(u",")
  uri_name = u"%s_%s" % (name[1].strip(), name[0].strip())
  uri = u'http://example.com/' + uri_name
  print uri

create_uri(u'Name, Non_Accent')
create_uri(u'Auberjonois, René')
```

Comment: Thanks in this example it works, the larger part of my code is passing in the name as a parameter, so `create_uri(row[1])` <from a .csv>, if i use `create_uri(unicode(row[1]))` I get the error again and I know I can't use `create_uri(urow[1]))`

Comment: That would be an interface.

Comment: Not clear on what you mean. Though is there any way to ensure unicode in the instance of passing the string variable and not a string as such?

Comment: No. You must examine your code for interfaces and decode/encode as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see by print statement, you are using python 2.x. That means you should define unicode chars via `\u` notation or use a `u` prefix for string. So, just change your line to

```
create_uri(u'Auberjonois, René') # note the u''
```

Also it looks like you don't need .encode for your parts after splitting - it's already unicode