# Possible to print 'é' as '%C3%A9' in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encode, rdflib

I am having a problem with passing a uri with unicode characters to `rdflib` for adding to a `Graph()`

So for instance, I want to run:

```
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
uri = 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/René_Auberjonois'
g.parse(uri)
```

But I get an ascii codec encoding error that is so common in Python.

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)`

If the uri were passed as `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ren%C3%A9_Auberjonois', it would be fine, the parser works if the string were in that fashion (sorry, I don't know what to call things, whether it's 'raw', 'escaped', 'unescaped' or otherwise).

is there any thing I can do to `uri` (it is not being set in this manner, it's being set through a function looping over a list of names) so that `print uri` would give `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ren%C3%A9_Auberjonois`?

*background*:
I originally asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326234/python-character-encoding-european-accents) question but adding `u` in front of a string is either not feasible with how the script is set up (i am not setting each string like: `s = 'René_Auberjonois'`) or doesn't actually work in the end when I pass it to rdflib (i.e. still getting the encoding error because it is being passed `http://dbpedia.org/resource/René_Auberjonois`)

Also if there are good resources for understanding the problem I am having here, that would be cool. I am confused by character encoding at the moment.

Comment: Why are you not using a `unicode` literal?

Comment: Because I am not well versed on this topic and am not sure how that would benefit me or what exactly that would entail (i.e. i am not a pro)

Comment: But you are at least reading the answers to your other questions, right?

Comment: yes and i appreciate your help, but even in using that advice, I have found that I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the percent encoded form is what you need, then you could use [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s='http://dbpedia.org/René_Auberjonois'
>>> urllib.quote(s)
'http%3A//dbpedia.org/Ren%C3%A9_Auberjonois'
>>> urllib.quote(s, safe=':')
'http:%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2FRen%C3%A9_Auberjonois'
>>> urllib.quote(s, safe=':/')
'http://dbpedia.org/Ren%C3%A9_Auberjonois'
>>>
```

Use the `safe` parameter to specify characters that shouldn't be quoted.  It defaults to `/`.